# cordova.exec in phonegap app (sqlite)

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I upgraded my phonegap application to version 3.0 by updating the sqlite plugin to the newest version (https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS)

By running i.e. this script (which run without problems before)

```
function onDeviceReady() {    
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
}
```

I get this log in my console:

```
The old format of this exec call has been removed (deprecated since 2.1). Change to: cordova.exec(null, null, "SQLitePlugin",...
```

There is no error, no warning, etc. just this information for every SQL statement. 
How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to update line 26 in SQLitePlugin.js

change from:

```
cordova.exec(success, error, "SQLitePlugin", method, [options]);
```

to:

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "SQLitePlugin", method, [options]);
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't have this line in my SQLitePlugin.js. See: https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS/blob/master/www/SQLitePlugin.js

Comment: I found the line "cordova.exec(success, error, "SQLitePlugin", method, [options]);" on line 26 at the link you provided here. Here is the same link with the line highlighted: https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS/blob/master/www/SQLitePlugin.js#L26